# Build Failure while executing Karate tests via command line

Tags: karate

In the sample Karate Test project 
We have a feature file and a runner class.

[image]

Trying to execute the test via command line using below command

```
mvn test -Dtest=UsersRunner
```

Thrown following error..

> [INFO]
>   ------------------------------------------------------------------------ [INFO] BUILD FAILURE [INFO]
>   ------------------------------------------------------------------------ [INFO] Total time: 35.422 s [INFO] Finished at:
>   2020-03-05T12:38:51+05:30 [INFO] Final Memory: 9M/124M [INFO]
>   ------------------------------------------------------------------------ [ERROR] Failed to execute goal
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test
>   (default-test) on project KarateBaseProject: No tests were executed! 
>   (Set -DfailIfNoTests=fals e to ignore this error.)

What is missing here

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't it be `mvn test -Dtest=UsersRunnerTest`

Also try creating a fresh project using version 0.9.5 and following these instructions: https://youtu.be/W-af7Cd8cMc

If you are still stuck, follow this process: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue